# Maven release plugin changes POM formatting

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When I executed `release:prepare` on one of my projects, it changed the formatting of the POM, which led to a huge diff over the entire file (see [this commit](https://github.com/beatngu13/pdf-zoom-wizard/commit/87ac68911d8afb495bbeb8e1c226bc079628e28d)). I assume this is somewhat related to the way the POM was formatted before, which I did with the standard Eclipse formatter settings.

Is there way to tell the release plugin not to do this? Or is there something I should change in my formatter settings?

**EDIT:** As mentioned by [khmarbaise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49085502/maven-release-plugin-changes-pom-formatting#comment85176634_49085502), I mixed up Linux and Windows EOL. However, IMO the release plugin shouldn't decide what to use for indentation and where to break lines.

Comment: It looks like you are using tabs for fomatting the XML which I do not recommend. Better use spaces for that...and make the handling of EOL consistent within the whole project (either go Linux or Windows way) but not both...

Comment: it is not only tabs. Attention to line `<project xmlns=" .....` it wasa multiline but become single-line
Here is one more example of this problem:
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/commit/29a635421d9292673bbaaf0c0693d2191dfb5f18

Comment: I created issue on plugin - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-1008

Comment: @RomanIvanov same issue. Looks like the bug was closed as wontfix.